# How to refresh images without page reloading after ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a script below that uploads images to the server. Upon completion it updates the img source by html. The issue I'm having is that I wrote my php code to rename the files to a predefined name (ext-pix0.png, ext-pix1.png, ext-pix3.png, etc.) when they are being uploaded. Because of this, the pictures on the screen won't refresh even though the new images replaced the old ones when uploading is done. I also turn off no cache, but it doesn't work. How do I get around this issue?

SCRIPT

```
<script>
  $('input[name="ext_pix[]"]').on('change',function(){
    var account_list = $('#account_list').val();
    var order_list = $('#order_list').val();
    var id_list = $('#id_list').val();
    var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'sql/ext-pix-upload.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success:function(data){
        $('#ext-pix0').html('<img src="accounts/'+account_list+'/'+order_list+'/pix/'+id_list+'/ext-pix0.png" height="103.5%" width="100%"/>').fadeIn(500);
        $('#ext-pix1').html('<img src="accounts/'+account_list+'/'+order_list+'/pix/'+id_list+'/ext-pix1.png" height="103.5%" width="100%"/>').fadeIn(500);
        $('#ext-pix2').html('<img src="accounts/'+account_list+'/'+order_list+'/pix/'+id_list+'/ext-pix2.png" height="103.5%" width="100%"/>').fadeIn(500);
        $('#ext-pix3').html('<img src="accounts/'+account_list+'/'+order_list+'/pix/'+id_list+'/ext-pix3.png" height="103.5%" width="100%"/>').fadeIn(500);
      },
      error: function(data){
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

HTML

```
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>

      <form>
        <div class="card-wrapper">
          <div class="card mt-3">
            <h5 class="card-header pb-2">Exterior Pictures</h5>
            <div class="card-block" style="height:322px">
              <div style="height:50%">
                <div id="ext-pix0" class="ext-pix">
                  <img src="images/profile/property-pix.png" height="103.5%" width="100%"/>
                </div>
                <div id="ext-pix1" class="ext-pix">
                  <img src="images/profile/property-pix.png" height="103.5%" width="100%"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="lower-row">
                <div id="ext-pix2" class="ext-pix">
                  <img src="images/profile/property-pix.png" height="103%" width="100%"/>
                </div>
                <div id="ext-pix3" class="ext-pix">
                  <img src="images/profile/property-pix.png" height="103%" width="100%"/>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="ext-btn">
                <input id="ext_pix" class="hidden" name="ext_pix[]" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple/>
                <label class="gi gi-camera mb-0 text-white" for="ext_pix" title="Change Picture"></label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: try to add a random string or timestamp at the end of the image file name in success function `ext-pix0.png?t=1234`

Comment: This method won't work since I need the file names to be specific so that I can pull them up later because these pictures are linked to a specific account.

Comment: you may want to *not* rename the files in the `php` and instead `return` their original names, and use that in the ajax success as `data` to update the DOM

Comment: The problem is I need those names to be specific so that the user can pull them up based on their choices of accout->order>id on the dropdown list.

Comment: the relationship of the filename to your model should be handled in the back end. It looks like your view is driving the backend here.

Comment: Yes, and my page is dynamic too.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to update img element in html file with id, inside the onSuccess() of ajax.

```
   <img id="img_id" src="#"/>
```

OnSuccess function of Ajax,

```
success: function (data) {  

          $("#img_id").attr("src", data.pictureUrl);    

     }
```

Comment: Did you check whether correct url is with data variable? try to echo data inside success function and check the output

Answer (score 0):

Clear the images first?

```
    success:function(data){
    $('#ext-pix0').html('');
    $('#ext-pix1').html('');
    $('#ext-pix2').html('');
    $('#ext-pix3').html('');
    $('#ext-pix0').html('<img src="accounts/'+account_list+'/'+order_list+'/pix/'+id_list+'/ext-pix0.png" height="103.5%" width="100%"/>').fadeIn(500);
    $('#ext-pix1').html('<img src="accounts/'+account_list+'/'+order_list+'/pix/'+id_list+'/ext-pix1.png" height="103.5%" width="100%"/>').fadeIn(500);
    $('#ext-pix2').html('<img src="accounts/'+account_list+'/'+order_list+'/pix/'+id_list+'/ext-pix2.png" height="103.5%" width="100%"/>').fadeIn(500);
    $('#ext-pix3').html('<img src="accounts/'+account_list+'/'+order_list+'/pix/'+id_list+'/ext-pix3.png" height="103.5%" width="100%"/>').fadeIn(500);
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
success:function(data){

    $('#ext-pix0').fadeOut('500', function(){
         $(this).find("img").attr("src", "accounts/'+account_list+'/'+order_list+'/pix/'+id_list+'/ext-pix0.png");
         $(this).fadeIn(500);
    });

    $('#ext-pix1').fadeOut('500', function(){
         $(this).find("img").attr("src", "accounts/'+account_list+'/'+order_list+'/pix/'+id_list+'/ext-pix1.png");
         $(this).fadeIn(500);
    });

    $('#ext-pix2').fadeOut('500', function(){
         $(this).find("img").attr("src", "accounts/'+account_list+'/'+order_list+'/pix/'+id_list+'/ext-pix2.png");
         $(this).fadeIn(500);
    });

    $('#ext-pix3').fadeOut('500', function(){
         $(this).find("img").attr("src", "accounts/'+account_list+'/'+order_list+'/pix/'+id_list+'/ext-pix3.png");
         $(this).fadeIn(500);
    });

},
```

Comment: Updating the source didn't work. I tried this method inititally but thought it would work with html rewrite but this method didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

> fadeOut "$('#ext-pix...')" before calling AJAX

```
 success:function(data){
        for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
            $('#ext-pix'+i).html('');
            let Image = $('<img/>',{src:'accounts/'+account_list+'/'+order_list+'/pix/'+id_list+'/ext-pix'+i+'.png' , style:'height:103.5%;width:100%';});
            $('#ext-pix'+i).html(Image).fadeIn(500);         
         }
    },
```

Comment: Don't work. I did this method first but switched to html and it didn't work as well.

Comment: Images are loaded again with the same name.  browser Used cache image . If you can create a different name each time the picture is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Please update what response you are getting in data in success function and update the src element only in ajax success. OR instead assign some class or ID to img tag and update only the src element.

```
<img class="ext-pix0" id="ext-pix0" src="images/profile/property-pix.png" height="103.5%" width="100%"/>
```

updated Script

```
success:function(data)
{
    for(vari=0;i<data.length.i++)
    {
      $('#ext-pix'+i).attr(src,'data[i].url').fadeIn(500);
    } 

  },
```